# move_base crashes with custom global planner whenever instantiating base_local_planner::CostmapModel

Tags: navigation, base-global-planner, plugin, global-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written my own global planner and have successfully registered the plugin so that move_base can detect it.

I am getting a problem where move_base will crash whenever I instantiate an instance of base_local_planner::CostmapModel.

I've removed all the code from my global planner so that it will run as a plugin that does nothing. This is what my initialize function looks like:

```
void FrontierPlanner::initialize(string name, Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros)
{
    map = costmap_ros;
    Costmap2D* costmap = map->getCostmap();
    base_local_planner::CostmapModel model(*costmap); //The offending line
}
```

This will cause move_base to crash. If I comment out the third line then it will run no problem. It compiles in both cases as well.

The error move_base gives me is:

```
 [FATAL] [1438809026.524028208]: Failed to create the bob/FrontierPlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: Failed to load library /home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libfrontier_planner_lib.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libfrontier_planner_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN18base_local_planner12CostmapModelE)
[move_base-5] process has died [pid 2554, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/move_base __name:=move_base __log:=/home/viki/.ros/log/6207c02a-3bb6-11e5-8754-080027c434d6/move_base-5.log].
log file: /home/viki/.ros/log/6207c02a-3bb6-11e5-8754-080027c434d6/move_base-5*.log
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215311/move_base-crashes-with-custom-global-planner-whenever-instantiating-base_local_planner::costmapmodel/) by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 363 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-06**:
Can you please give some more details (maybe link to a gist)?
Showing your `*plugin.xml` for this planner, more details on the implementation as well as the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`.

Otherwise, we can only guess... But something seems to be wrong the way you export your library...

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2015-08-06**:
I forgot a target_link_libraries in my CMakeLists.txt. I wasn't linking the library with my plugin to catkin_libraries.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-07**:
can you then post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct? Helps keeping ROS Answers clean ;-)

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2015-08-07**:
I can't accept my own answer because I don't have a high enough reputation lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forgot to target_link_libraries in my CMakeLists.txt file. I wasn't linking the library with my plugin to catkin_libraries.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) with karma: 363 on 2015-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1